# Jaxb Maven plugins and represent null element as null, not as instance

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

Scenario, XML example:

```
<outer>
    <inner />
</outer>
```

I need to use Mavens Jaxb plugin, any will do, as long as it will generate xml from xsd. The schema states that outer element must occur once, and inner element has minoccurs 0. The inner element has also attribute, which is also minoccurs 0. Element having more than just a value makes it as a class. I'm receiving the example xml, and after doing unmarshalling, it saves the inner element as "empty instance" and not null. When I'm doing marshalling again, I get validation errors because the inner element is not ignored though it's "null" in sense.

What I need is a way to make these elements with just /> ending and nothing else to be read as null, so they wont be marshalled or validated, just ignored, dropped, unless they are specified to occur. So the XML would be marshalled to be simply:

```
<outer />
```

I read that there are some ways to achieve this with modifying the xml classes ( [Create Null Object Unmarshalling Empty Element with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426297/create-null-object-unmarshalling-empty-element-with-jaxb) and [JAXB empty element unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921196/jaxb-empty-element-unmarshalling)), but since my xml classes are generated with maven jaxb plugin, the modifications are ofcourse overwritten every time the classes are generated.

Is there any way to achieve this with jaxb maven plugins or is there some other way to apply the changes on top of generated codes so that they are easily managed? Other suggestions are welcomed as well. The received xml cannot be modified and the result must be the way I described. IF there is something that can be added to schema to get this behavior that is acceptable as well.